Delete all entrys if checkbox is checked
I have created a form that displays a list of database entries. There is a checkbox for each value. When I check the checkbox, I want to delete this entry.
My form class looks like this:
//Räume auslesen
        $rooms = $DB->get_records_sql( 
                'SELECT LBTB.id, LBTB.datum, LBTB.roomid, LBTB.ustd, 
                        LBTB.userid, RAUM.raumname, RAUM.raumnummer 
                FROM {bs_steinweg} LBTB
                    LEFT JOIN {bs_raume} RAUM ON LBTB.roomid = RAUM.id
                WHERE roomid > "0"
            ');

        foreach ($rooms as $room) {
            $newdate = date( 'd.m.Y', strtotime( $room->datum ) );
            $mform->addElement('html', '<tr><th scope="row">');
            $mform->addElement('advcheckbox', 'roomid[]','','','', $room->id);
            $mform->addElement('html', '</th><td>');
            $mform->addElement("html", "$room->raumname");
            $mform->addElement('html', '</td><td>');
            $mform->addElement("html", "$newdate");
            $mform->addElement('html', '</td><td>');
            $mform->addElement("html", "$room->ustd");
            $mform->addElement('html', '</td></tr>');
            $mform->addElement('hidden', 'id', $room->id);
            $mform->setType('id', PARAM_INT);
        }

I try to delete the data like this:
if ( !empty( $fromform->delete ) ) {
        if ( !empty( $fromform->roomid ) ) {
            foreach ( $fromform->roomid as $room_id ) {
                print_r($fromform->id);
                /* $DB->delete_records( 'bs_steinweg', [ 'id' => $room_id ] ); */
            }
            /* $getDeleteCanceld = get_string( 'getDeleteCanceld', 'local_buchungssystem' );
            redirect( $CFG->wwwroot . '/local/buchungssystem/meine_fach_buchungen_sw.php', $getDeleteCanceld ); */
        } else {
            // Handle the case where no rooms were selected.
            $getDeleteCanceld = get_string( 'noRoomsSelected', 'local_buchungssystem' );
            redirect( $CFG->wwwroot . '/local/buchungssystem/meine_fach_buchungen_sw.php', $getDeleteCanceld );
        }
    }

The output with print_r($room_id) does not give me any value.
The output with print_r($fromform->id) only gives me the last value. Even if I select the first value, it always gives me the last ID.
Counting the whole thing up with a for loop also doesn't output any value. It doesn't matter whether I output print_r($room_id) or print_r($fromform->id):
if ( !empty( $fromform->delete ) ) {
        if ( !empty( $fromform->roomid ) ) {
            foreach ( $fromform->roomid as $room_id ) {
                for ( $i = 0; $i <= $room_id; $i++ ) {
                print_r($room_id);
                }
                /* $DB->delete_records( 'bs_steinweg', [ 'id' => $room_id ] ); */
            }
            /* $getDeleteCanceld = get_string( 'getDeleteCanceld', 'local_buchungssystem' );
            redirect( $CFG->wwwroot . '/local/buchungssystem/meine_fach_buchungen_sw.php', $getDeleteCanceld ); */
        } else {
            // Handle the case where no rooms were selected.
            $getDeleteCanceld = get_string( 'noRoomsSelected', 'local_buchungssystem' );
            redirect( $CFG->wwwroot . '/local/buchungssystem/meine_fach_buchungen_sw.php', $getDeleteCanceld );
        }
    }

My solution:
$mform->addElement('advcheckbox', "laptopid[$laptop->id]",'','','', $laptop->id);

The processing:
if ( !empty( $fromform->delroomsw ) ) {
    if ( !empty( $fromform->roomid ) ) {
        $checked_values = $fromform->roomid;
        foreach ( $checked_values as $val ) {
            //Räume auslesen
            $rooms = $DB->get_record_sql( "SELECT * FROM {bs_steinweg} WHERE id = $val" );
            if ( $rooms->userid == $USER->id ) {
                $DB->delete_records( 'bs_steinweg', [ 'id' => $val ] );
            } else {
                $getDeleteCanceld = get_string( 'noDeleteRights', 'local_buchungssystem' );
                redirect( $CFG->wwwroot . '/local/buchungssystem/meine_buchungen.php', $getDeleteCanceld );
            }
        }
        $getDeleteCanceld = get_string( 'getDeleteCanceld', 'local_buchungssystem' );
        redirect( $CFG->wwwroot . '/local/buchungssystem/meine_buchungen.php', $getDeleteCanceld );
    }

}


You need to make sure, that you're assigning unique names to your input fields. In this case you add a hidden input field using
$mform->addElement('hidden', 'id', $room->id);

with the name id and the value $room->id. Then for the next room in your for loop the name id is overwritten, since you use the same name as for the previous room. You could for example create unique names by doing this:
$mform->addElement('hidden', 'id-'.strval($room->id), $room->id);

The same goes for your advcheckbox fields.
Your revised form code:
foreach ($rooms as $room) {
    $newdate = date( 'd.m.Y', strtotime( $room->datum ) );
    $mform->addElement('html', '<tr><th scope="row">');
    $mform->addElement('advcheckbox', 'roomid'.strval($room->id),'','','', array(0, 1));
    $mform->addElement('html', '</th><td>');
    $mform->addElement("html", "$room->raumname");
    $mform->addElement('html', '</td><td>');
    $mform->addElement("html", "$newdate");
    $mform->addElement('html', '</td><td>');
    $mform->addElement("html", "$room->ustd");
    $mform->addElement('html', '</td></tr>');
    $mform->addElement('hidden', 'id-'.strval($room->id), $room->id);
    $mform->setType('id', PARAM_INT);
 }

You'd need to test if your deletion code works or if you need to tweak it regarding  the changes. I also highly advise you to read more about the usage of advcheckbox in the docs here. There you can also find more info about the name parameter and how to read the data received.

OK, I have now adjusted the two fields. I hope I have understood you and the documentation correctly: $mform->addElement('hidden', 'id'.strval($room->id), $room->id);             $mform->addElement('advcheckbox', 'roomid'.strval($room->id),'','','', array(0, 1));. However, it always tells me that I haven't selected a room. That means it doesn't notice that a checkbox is checked.
Since I have now assigned the name "Unique" with the ID, how can I access the value?

@Sascha You nailed it! You can get the value of an entry using $fromform->entry['text']; as seen here. You could for example again loop through all rooms and check the value of the advcheckbox. Meaning you reuse your snippet with $rooms = $DB->get_records_sql([...]) and then check if the entry roomid-$room->id is set. You could add a - between the concatination of "roomid" and the id, so it is easier to read, if you want. If everything works the hidden element also becomes obsolete

I think your way of getting me to the solution is good. At the moment I just can't see the forest for the trees. My English isn't perfect enough to understand everything. I think my approach is going in the right direction. However, I've got a knot in my head somewhere and I think I'm mixing something up. Can I ask for a more specific solution tip in this case?
I edited my attempted solution above.

[German 1/2] Kein Problem, ich kann meine Kommentare auch auf Deutsch schreiben und sie gleich für andere mit DeepL übersetzen. Das ist auch für mich einfacher haha. Du kannst mal versuchen die Variablen $fromform und $rooms zu printen. Dann siehst du, womit du arbeitest. Das kannst du einerseits machen mit dd($fromform, $rooms) oder mit dem üblichen print_r([...]) [...].

[German 2/2] Ich kenne mich nicht zu 100% mit Moodle aus, daher nimm nicht mein Wort als die reine Wahrheit, aber so weit ich weiß sind die Values der Checkboxen jetzt unter $fromform['roomid'.$room->id] erreichbar, da wir vorher die Namen so vergeben haben. Am Besten kannst du deine Frage nochmal mit den Ergebnissen vom dump and die (dd) oder printen updaten.

[English 1/2] No problem, I can also write my comments in German and translate them for others with DeepL. That's easier for me too haha. You can try to print the variables $fromform and $rooms. Then you can see what you are working with. You can do this with dd($fromform, $rooms) or with the usual print_r([...]) [...].

[English 2/2] I'm not 100% familiar with Moodle, so don't take my word for it, but as far as I know the values of the checkboxes are now accessible under $fromform['roomid'.$room->id] as that's how we named them before. The best thing to do is to update your question with the results of the dump and die (dd) or print.

My solution:
$mform->addElement('advcheckbox', "laptopid[$laptop->id]",'','','', $laptop->id);

The processing:
if ( !empty( $fromform->delroomsw ) ) {
    if ( !empty( $fromform->roomid ) ) {
        $checked_values = $fromform->roomid;
        foreach ( $checked_values as $val ) {
            //Räume auslesen
            $rooms = $DB->get_record_sql( "SELECT * FROM {bs_steinweg} WHERE id = $val" );
            if ( $rooms->userid == $USER->id ) {
                $DB->delete_records( 'bs_steinweg', [ 'id' => $val ] );
            } else {
                $getDeleteCanceld = get_string( 'noDeleteRights', 'local_buchungssystem' );
                redirect( $CFG->wwwroot . '/local/buchungssystem/meine_buchungen.php', $getDeleteCanceld );
            }
        }
        $getDeleteCanceld = get_string( 'getDeleteCanceld', 'local_buchungssystem' );
        redirect( $CFG->wwwroot . '/local/buchungssystem/meine_buchungen.php', $getDeleteCanceld );
    }

}

